# CGI print before process exits

Tags: perl, cgi

I am aware of the other topic related to this issue, my problem is that the suggested solution didn't work for me.
This is the test script I am using:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -sW
use CGI::Carp qw( fatalsToBrowser );
use CGI qw/:standard/;
use 5.12.0;

my $q = CGI->new;

$|++;
print $q->header('text/html');

print 0;
sleep(2);
print 1;
sleep(5);
print 2;
exit;
```

And even with autoflush true, all output gets buffered and output only when the execution of the script is finished. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Is this mod_perl? Are you testing this in a browser or simply by running the script from the command line?

Comment: browser, and now I am executing as regular cgi script without mod_perl

Comment: Congrats on getting the 9000th question tagged as Perl here!

Comment: Haha didn't even realize that, thanks I guess :) Shame it was wasted on such a stupid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow this is stupid, it seems that chrome on linux actually has its own output buffering. I've tested the identical script in firefox and it works...
Thanks everyone for the help though!

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you run this from the shell?

This depends on the way the web server handles CGI.  Some buffer the whole thing to provide an accurate `Content-Length`.  In my recent memory, Apache does not buffer (though it may used to).

Configure your web server to use [Non-Parsed Headers](http://webdeveloper.com/cgi-perl/cgi_http_headers_optimize_cgi.html) which will pump data as available.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The script works from shell. Weird thing is that apache used to only buffer the output prior to 1.3, thus non-parsed headers shouldn't be an issue; which however doesn't help as I still don't know what is the problem...

Comment: Sounds crazy, but invoke/exec the perl interpreter from a CGI shell script, does that change anything?